# Summing rows to arbitrary columns in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am trying to vectorise a for loop that sums a vector to a index defined by another vector. There are a large number of vectors to sum. This is done easily in a for loop but perhaps not obviously to me, in a vectorised manner.

An random example would be:

t = rand(10, 5);

c = randi([1 5], 1, 10);

Basically, I now need to sum across each row until the corresponding column given by the same index of c as current row t. The return value would be a vector of the row sum to its respective column c(i). I have explored as many manipulations of the sum function that I can think of but none achieve the end result.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is using [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create a mask of the values that you want to include in each row sum:

```
result = sum(t .* bsxfun(@le, 1:size(t,2), c(:)), 2);
```

In Matlab R2016b or newer you can use [implicit expansion](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/implicit-expansion-matlab-r2016b/) instead of `bsxfun`:

```
result = sum(t .* (1:size(t,2) <= c(:)), 2)
```